# How to Parse simple data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to do a simple parse of some data coming from a field.  Example:

```
1/2
1/3
10/20
12/31
```

I simply need to Split or Parse this on "/".  Is there a simple function that will allow me to do this?

Comment: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html  Check this Page Help U

Comment: That seems to be more for Java than for BigQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '1/2' list UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '1/3' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '10/20' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '15/' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '12/31' 
)
SELECT id, 
  SPLIT(list, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS first_element,
  SPLIT(list, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS second_element
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY id
```

with result as below

```sql
Row id  first_element   second_element   
1   1   1               2    
2   2   1               3    
3   3   10              20   
4   4   15       
5   5   12              31
```

Comment: Thank you!  So [SAFE_OFFSET] is the answer... Any way in plain English you can explain what it is doing?

Comment: let's say some row has (by accident or by design) just one element - so if you will use OFFSET() to try to extract respective element that does not exist - query will fail - but if you will use SAFE_OFFSET - it will not! see updated example and try there to replace SAFE_OFFSET with just OFFSET  - you will see the difference

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following SQL functions:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#split
- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_extract_all

For example with `SPLIT` you can do

```
SELECT parts[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]
FROM (SELECT SPLIT(field) parts FROM UNNEST(["1/2", "10/20"]) field)
```

Comment: I found the Split function but it seems to do a very odd thing It almost turns the results into an array.  Placing the items on different rows.  I have never seen anything like this and I am not sure how to handle it.
For example if I have 
    C1    C2    C3
    01     02    01/01
    02     03    02
My return is: 
    C1    C2    C3
    01     02    01
                     01
    02    03     02

Comment: Sorry I can not figure out the formatting on this stupid place...  but it is splitting the results and placing it on a second row completely alone.  This is neat, but is there not a simple parse function that will parse a string into an additional column?? I feel like that is a super basic easy function.

Comment: I added example of how to use SPLIT in the answer.